# A calendar with powerful alerts

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, calendar, alarm, google-calendar

I just bought a Samsung Galaxy 2, coming from a Nokia 3600.

My old cell phone had a quite simple calendar app but when it was supposed to alert me it kept ringing and vibrating until I dismiss it.

I could quietly use an alert as a morning alarm if I knew, for example, I'll have to wake up at 6:00 on next 12/25.

In new one calendar just beeps once and I already missed a ton of appointments this way.

Moreover I started using alarms but there's no vibration available and it's limited in time setting.

I'm looking for an app to suit my needs, possibly syncing with Google Calendar, not too much bells and whistles but not mandatory.

Any advice?

Thank you

## Edit:

As a note to who, gently is answering how to set calendar notification:

Please let me know also how to set it the way I need i.e. to **make it ring until dismissed** (or after, say, max 1 minute in case I'm far from the phone).

Otherwise changing from *blip* to *din don* won't help that much because I already tested it losing some appointments. :)

Comment: My standard Clock app plays the alarm and vibrates. Rather obnoxiously I might add. You can change the notification sound that gets used; have you tried that?

Comment: @AlEverett: I'm using Clock alarm but it does not vibrates nor I can see any setting anout it. However it comes hard to put a note far in time, for example birthdays alerts and so on. I can't fill it with tens of alarms just 'cause the calendar alerts suck...

Comment: Ok, sorry, I found vibration setting for alarm but I'm still unable to set a proper alert for an appointment, say, coming in 10 days.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Calendar Snooze](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.bitfire.development.calendarsnooze) can repeat reminders until you acknowledge them, forever. It works with the default Calendar app, and will let it keep syncing with google.

You can customize how often the notification repeats, how many times (including "Keep Repeating"), and you can customize two sets of reminders, for example repeating every minute for 5 minutes, and then ever 5 minutes for an hour. It can also use notifications, the LED, text-to-speech, and alert popups.

It also (as the name suggests) allows a very powerful snooze mechanism, with completely customizable snoozes.

Comment: Thanks, I will try it! Anyway: 700Kb for adding just a simple snooze seem to me overkill but if it works I'll be happy of installing

Comment: A Galaxy S 2 has 2 GB of storage for apps (/data). That's four times what I have, with about 200 apps installed. I wouldn't worry about it. ;)

Comment: I accept your answer even if I went with another app [CalendarAlarmHelper](https://market.android.com/details?id=net.DailyTimer.CalendarAlarmHelper) (primarily because it's cheaper and lighter) but I found it thanks to your link so... thank you ^^

Answer (score 1):

Open the Calendar App. Press MENU > SETTINGS > scroll down to NOTIFICATION SETTINGS.

You can then choose your desired ringtone and whether an alert should pop up or merely a notification bar update shows along with Vibrate options.

As a calendar alternative, check out [Jorte](https://market.android.com/details?id=jp.co.johospace.jorte).

The Galaxy S2's alarm interface has options for recurring alarms as well as preset Snooze modes.

UPDATE: [Nudnik](https://market.android.com/details?id=amProgz.nudnik.full) and [Calendar Event Reminder](https://market.android.com/details?id=de.foobarsoft.calendareventreminder) are calendar nag apps that seem to offer the functionality you're looking for.

Comment: About Notification Settings please see my comment to KalEl answer. Again about alarm, I already use it with multiple alarms and snooze but, again, see my answer to  Al Everett in question comments... I wonder why my 100€ Nokia was able to alert me in a way I was sure to get it and a 600€ android is not. Maybe android engineers was thinkin' I'd passed my whole day looking at the phone screen holding it in my right hand... I'll check your suggested alternative.

Comment: I saw your update and try apps you suggest

Answer (score 1):

Im trying now [CalendarAlarmHelper](https://market.android.com/details?id=net.DailyTimer.CalendarAlarmHelper) that's way cheaper than TREE suggestion.

Free version expires after 7 days but has full functionalities.

Answer (score -1):

Now that Astrid has stopped,trying out TicTac. Working quite well and seems reliable

Comment: A link to the app would make this more useful for the OP

Comment: And some information on how, specifically, it fixes the OP's problem would be good, too.

Answer (score -2):

You could try Astrid, I find it very useful as a task manager

Comment: Who asked for a task manager?

Answer (score -2):

Calendar -> Settings -> Notification Settings -> Select Ringtone.

Also set "alerts and notifications" in the same menu to Alerts.

Comment: I already saw it, all sounds last no more than a second and I don't find any option to tell it to ring until dismissed, **that's what I asked**. I see there's an option for always vibrating and it's on but if it just vibrates **once for a second**, as the alarm, then I know why I never felt it...

Comment: Here's an idea - if you use an alternate SMS app like Handcent or GoSMS pro or RingDroid - they have an alternative music picker which can be used to select songs from your media/audio folder. That'll give you a loooong ringtone.

Comment: Yes it would be a long ringtone, but once again, *it does not answer the question that is asked*.